# Show SnackBar in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code that I want to use to show a snackbar but it won't work and I don't know why:

home-screen.dart is where it all starts and I define a scaffoldKey that I pass down to another widget.

```
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();


return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
       ...
      ),
   
      body: Column(
            ...
            AnotherWidget(scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey
```

another-widget.dart

```
final helpers = Helpers();

start() async {
    try {
      if (energy == 0) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        helpers.showSnackWithKey(widget.scaffoldKey, "Not enough energy");
        showRemaining = true;
        return;
      }

return Card(
      shadowColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ...
          ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            start();
          },
          ...
```

helpers.dart

```
  showSnackWithKey(scaffoldKey, message) {
    print(message);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          elevation: 3,
          content: Text(message),
        ),
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use null assertion. Instead of `ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext)` in helper, use `ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext!)`

`GlobalKey.currentContext` is nullable but `ScaffoldMessenger.of` doesn't accept nullable. Also since `scaffoldKey` is `dynamic` type, there is no IDE warning.

Edit: I encounter the null error above once, but couldn't reproduce it. I tried to run provided the code, it can show message as expected

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyWidget({super.key});

  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: AnotherWidget(scaffoldKey: _scaffoldKey),
    );
  }
}

class AnotherWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AnotherWidget({required this.scaffoldKey});
  final scaffoldKey;

  @override
  State<AnotherWidget> createState() => _AnotherState();
}

class _AnotherState extends State<AnotherWidget> {
  final helpers = Helpers();

  start() async {
    try {
      if (0 == 0) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        helpers.showSnackWithKey(widget.scaffoldKey, "Not enough energy");
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('click'),
      onPressed: () {
        start();
      },
    );
  }
}

class Helpers {
  Helpers();

  showSnackWithKey(scaffoldKey, message) {
    print(message);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext!).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        elevation: 3,
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. thank you for answering. it didn't fix it.